# Google Drive always returns labels.viewed: true

Tags: google-drive-api

I am attempting to monitor a folder in Google Drive and determine when one of the files changes. Once the file has changed, I would like to treat it as if it had been viewed so further updates or edits to it, or even just marking it unviewed, would cause it to be processed by my application again.

Using the `changes.watch` API call, I can get a watch notification when a change is made. For example, when I use the Drive UI menu item "Mark as unviewed", I will get the change notification, and fetching the corresponding change, I get a modificationDate field that is set correctly, but the file.labels.viewed is set to true. This is similarly true if I use `files.patch` and set labels.viewed to false and if I just use `files.get` to get the metadata about the file. In every case, the API seems to indicate the file has been viewed.

Is there a way to correctly handle this flag?

Answer (score 1):

When you check the files the first time save the Etag

etag": "\"9Bs6b7Q8Ry7SsffJEXXjXAp89zk/MTM4MTg0NDEyOTg4Mw\""

The next time you check the file see if the Etag is the same or not.  If its not the same as the one you have before then its changed.